# How can I put the equations in two lines after closing the delimiter?

Tags: equations, delimiters

I want to put the equations in two lines, help me pls..

```
$\left.
\begin{aligned}
   f(z)&=\cos2z\\\\
   f'(z)&=-2\sin2z\\\\
   f''(z)&=-4\cos2z\\\\
   f'''(z)&=8\cos2z\\\\
   f^{IV}(z)&=16\sin2z\\\\
   f^{V}(z)&=-32\cos2z\\\\
\end{aligned}
\right\}\quad 
f^{19}(z)=\pm 2^{19} \sin(2z)  \land f^{19}(0)=\pm 2^{19} \sin(2\times 0)
$
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows how you achieved the output ou showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `rcases` from `mathtools` and `aligned`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{rcases*}
  \begin{aligned}
    f(z)     &=\cos2z\\
    f'(z)    &=-2\sin2z\\
    f''(z)   &=-4\cos2z\\
    f'''(z)  &=8\cos2z\\
    f^{IV}(z)&=16\sin2z\\
    f^{V}(z) &=-32\cos2z\\
   \end{aligned}
\end{rcases*} 
\begin{aligned}
f^{19}(z)&=\pm 2^{19} \sin(2z)  \land\\ 
f^{19}(0)&=\pm 2^{19} \sin(2\times 0)
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank, very much.I was about to try aligned, but I had my doubts. But `rcases` is necesary?

Comment: Would look nicer if aligned on the right, in my opinion.

Comment: Add `{}` after `\land` in order to fix the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

**This too work**

```
$\left.
\begin{aligned}
f(z)&=\cos2z\\\\
f'(z)&=-2\sin2z\\\\
f''(z)&=-4\cos2z\\\\
f'''(z)&=8\cos2z\\\\
f^{IV}(z)&=16\sin2z\\\\
f^{V}(z)&=-32\cos2z\\\\
\end{aligned}
\right\}\quad 
\begin{aligned}
f^{19}(z)&=\pm 2^{19} \sin(2z)  \\
 f^{19}(0)&=\pm 2^{19} \sin(2\times 0)
\end{aligned}
$
```

[image]